# Change location of .project and .cproject files in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

For an existing Eclipse CDT project in a given location, we can also find the files .project and .cproject in that given location.
Is there a way to store these files in a complete separated location ?

Comment: The question is, why you should do that? Without these files, Eclipse does not know what to do with the whole directory, so it is naturally to have it there and to check it out and commit it to a version control system.

Comment: The reason is keep in different locations the project files of different developers who share the same code

Comment: But there are other mechanisms to do just that. And the `.project` files should be shared by each other ...

Comment: why should they be shared? My definition of project may have characteristics that are not shared by other users (paths, env variables, etc...)
Do you have any suggestion for another mechanism?

Comment: Why should they  be different per developer? It is so much easier to define all characteristics for a project that works on each desktop without modification, even on a new machine like the build environment where you have the same problem. If you want to separate something that is dependent on each developer, this may be done by a build process that uses the ID of the developer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about the .cproject file, but the .project file is expected to be at the root of the project, and I don't think you can do anything about this, except possibly to link it somewhere else. The .project file is used by the Eclipse core resources mechanism.

Comment: Creating an empty project file with a link to another location (where the real shared code is) made the trick